# Sails.js 0.10 and passport

Tags: session, socket.io, sails.js, passport.js

I was fiddling with sails.js and passport. Seems they are mend to be used together.

I have made the user models available in de db. And I am able to use the authentication by bcryptjs. This works, but dearly want to like to automatically authenticate every call, and mostly socket.io blueprint calls.

Still,  I am searching for an elegant method to enable the sails.js way of integrating passport.
There are many examples, but seem a bit out-dated, not sure.

Important is the sockets. They need to be authenticated.

For e.g. every io.socket CRUD method, would be nice.

Kind regards

---

I found a link (http://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/) that's pointing me in the right direction, but still not clear how this is reflected in for instance controllers

What I am trying to manage, is to have the custom api calls authenticated before they are called (configured in routes.js or by means of blueprints).

e.g:

OrderController:

```
module.exports = {

placeOrder: function (req, res) {
  if (true === req.isSocket) {
    // Pseudo code: 
    if (passport.authenticated(['user','admin'])) {
      Order.save();
    }

    // end pseudo code
  }
}

}
```

How should/is the above method secured, and I am I able to use for instance user-roles here?

Comment: Check sails passport example in sails 101:
https://github.com/sails101/using-passport For something more complex ( with plugins ) check my project we.js how extends sails.js with sails 0.10.x hooks. Example in https://github.com/wejs/we-example

Answer (score 0):

I know two good solution for you question:

- [sails-auth](http://www.geektantra.com/2013/08/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js/)
- [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth)

Both implements passport, I recommend the first one, because it creates a layer to handle all authentication difficulties in model and services